# Regex Notepad++ Insert new line before every uppercase word containing more than 3 characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

can anyone help with a search/replace that will insert a new line before every uppercase word. i have been searching and any query i run replaces the uppercase word. any help appreciated.

i have one row with text like :

```
ALEXANDER Agnes Died May 10 1841 age 80 mother of George of Grange-Foyle ALEXANDER Anne Died Aug 5 1912 wife of William Alexander ALEXANDER Elizabeth Died Nov 27 1794 age 75 wife of Joseph Alexander ALEXANDER George Farmer of Grange-Foyle
```

And i would like it like this, i.e a new line for every surname

```
>    ALEXANDER Agnes Died May 10 1841 age 80 mother of George of Grange-Foyle
>    ALEXANDER Anne Died Aug 5 1912 wife of William Alexander
>    ALEXANDER Elizabeth Died
>    ALEXANDER George Farmer of Grange-Foyle
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for all 2+ upercase characters preceeded with a whitespace, place them in group and replace them with a newline preceding the captured group, e.g.

```
Find what:    (?:\s)([A-Z]{2,})
Replace with: \n\1
```

And make sure `Match case` is selected and that Search & Replace works in `Regular expression` mode.

Comment: many thanks - had a combination of those, just not in the one line

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
(?!\A)\b[A-Z]{3,}\b
```

And replace this with

```
\n$0
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5ZzbcN/1/).

Comment: The fix is easy: 1) Make sure the Match Case is turned on, 2) use `\n$0` replacement